# VitrtualBox Connection to GitLab by using SSH keys

Tags: ssh, windows-10, gitlab, ubuntu-18.04

I'm stuck with a little ssh problem. I'm working with a Windows10 which has its pair of ssh keys generated via PuttyGen (rsa) by using domain's mail. I use this pair to connect via Ssh to my GitLab repository and all works fine.
I decided to create a Ubuntu VM via VirtualBox on the same machine, then I generated a new ssh keys pair into the VM using

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my.email@example.com" -b 4096
```

with the same mail of windows10's domain. After that I added this new public key into my GitLab account. However, when I test this new pair of keys via

```
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com
```

where "gitlab.com" is my gitlab repository, I receive, along with some debug messages (which don't contain any useful information)

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

Now, my question is as follows:

is there something that I should do differently as usual to setup a new pair of SSh keys into a VirtualMachine which use the same network of the Host machine? Or, theoretically, should it work fine just as I did?

Thank you

EDIT: I've also tried to copy the same VM SSH keys into my Windows machine, replacing the old one, and they works. So it's not a generation key problem, I think it's really a problem of VirtualBox or Virtualization in general, any help?

Comment: Have you added this key in your Gitlab account?

Comment: Yes yes, I've written it. I've also copied that VM key into the host windows machine to understand if it was a key generation problem, but the ssh via windows works, so I think it's a virtualization problem

Comment: I don't think key gen is problem as I have worked with VMs working fine with ssh in my Ubuntu VMs. Can you try "ssh -vvv git@gitlab.com" and check at what step it fails?